# cocos2d: skeletal animation apply to cloth mesh which is added by addMesh to the character

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-android

I create many clothes which are saved in separate files, and we add cloth Mesh to the human character, the human character is acting with skeleton, but the cloth not, do you know how to make it work with skeleton?

thanks very much!

~lindy

Answer (score 1):

You should create `MeshSkin` object by using Skeleton object of the human. And set the MeshSkin object to the cloth mesh.